# CodeIgniter: Load a different view based on screen width instead of creating a mobile version?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I thought of loading a different view folder `m.view` instead of having `m.project_name`. I am "autoloading" the templates so I only have the following in the controller:

```
$this->load_views('home/index.php', $data);
```

And in `My_Controller.php`:

```
function load_views($view, $data = []) {
    // load m.view for mobile
    $this->load->view('templates/header'. $data);
    $this->load->view($view, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}
```

In my `footer.php`:

```
<script>
    if (screen.width < 937) {
        window.location('http://localhost/m.project_name');
    }
</script>
```

But think of being in http://localhost/project_name/controller/method/p1, you'll be redirected to the default page.

Comment: If you want to send mobile pages to mobile devices, you have to detect this before you even send any page to prevent this weird stuff where you start redirecting on the client. When a request is sent to your server, the headers of the request contain information about the device/browser your user is working with. So based on  that information you can decide what you wish to do.

Comment: Yeah, maybe sending the width through query strings. But that means I won't have clean URL and have to set query strings to all my links.

Comment: Seriously - Use a front end framework to do this. The three top ones are Bootstrap 3: http://getbootstrap.com Foundation: http://foundation.zurb.com and Jquery Mobile https://jquerymobile.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually ask a question so I'm not sure what you were looking for, but maybe this will be helpful..

You can use this in your controller to determine if the client is a mobile browser and just send the correct UI the first time instead og making mobile browsers wait for the full version to load and then making them wait again for the mobile version to load.

```
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4))){
    // load mobile view
}else{
    // load regular view
}
```

Got that from [here](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/).

However this approach is rather outdated. Modern websites should use a responsive theme like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to adjust a single theme to fit nicely in any size browser window using CSS [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)..

Comment: Wow, I haven't thought about that. Thanks. But still this will only go based on user agents there's still variation of width to think about. Think tablets for example. So, i guess i'll go with responsiveness.

Comment: Go to this URL: www.51degrees.com , here they provide you with a package that determines whether the user is using a mobile, tablet, or other stuff. For a project Im working on at my company we're using the paid version of this, but they have a free one as well, although Im not sure what features you can use with the free version.